# How to detect possible presence of barcode in image? (When value cannot be read)

Tags: c#, opencv, barcode

I have a multi-page document that is being scanned. Sometimes, either because the document was a fax or simply a bad scan, the barcode reading software cannot determine the value of the barcode.

The barcode could be on any page within the document, however, this page should be the "header" page and moved to the front. How can I automatically detect that the image has a barcode when the value cannot be read with typical barcode reading tools?

The usual barcode type is Code39, but sometimes it could be DataMatrix. I am mostly concerned about detecting mis-read Code39, as I think it will be easier to detect.

Comment: the first thought would be to detect only the vertical lines using the `probabilistic Hough line transform` and checking for angle in OpenCV. After that check whether these obtained lines are all roughly the same height and their y-positions are comparable. This could be the first step.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at:
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/