# Detecting blank images (the image expected is a barcode) in c#

Tags: c#, barcode, imaging

I am basically processing bar codes with an open source software. But the tool sometimes fails detecting no bar code at all.

So I want to myself check wether the image was really blank or it contains some sort of bar code.

My images are produced through scanning and they only contain a bar code (if they are not blank) and some noise images produced by the scanning. So my problem could be even down to checking if the image contains a significant amount of concentrated black pixels to differentiate it from white space images with noise.

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757295/how-to-detect-possible-presence-of-barcode-in-image-when-value-cannot-be-read) SO question, but the suggestion was to use "probabilistic Hough line transform" which I found a little bit an overkill for my situation.

I have also checked out [this](http://www.chinhdo.com/20080910/detect-blank-images/) but it has unsafe code.
I am looking for a managed C# solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second sample that you linked to uses `unsafe` code only to speed up access to pixel values in your bitmap. You can easily replace all that by using the `Bitmap`'s `GetPixel()` method instead (the downside is that this will then be extremely slow, but it will probably still be fast enough for your purposes).

As far as the `unsafe` code goes, however, there is no reason to worry about using it. The only issue with the `unsafe` tag is that some users (depending on their permissions levels) may not be able to run the code, although I have never actually encountered this potential problem myself.

Comment: There is a midway between `GetPixel()` and `unsafe` pointer arithmetic code, and that is the `Marshal` class. See for example this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1563170/860585

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is computer vision, sounds fancy but it is very simple now (5 years back it was not that popular ans somehow difficult) take a look at these articles:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28465/Easy-to-use-Wrapper-DLL-for-Intel-s-OpenCV-Library

http://www.chinhdo.com/20080910/detect-blank-images/

Answer (score 0):

You could use this C# library [OpenSURF](http://www.chrisevansdev.com/computer-vision-opensurf.html) and look at the value for the SURF feature descriptor vector. I am not sure if it is "safe"